# How do I pass a prop to a stylesheet in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a prop called isProfile which is used by a component (Feed) that uses the stylesheet below. I want to conditionally render the height of the container based on whether the isProfile prop is set as true or false.

```
function Feed({isProfile}){
    return(
      <View style={style.container}>
      </View>

)

}

    
const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
       backgroundColor:colors.primary,                     
       width:windowWidth,
       justifyContent:"center",
       height: isProfile ? windowHeight : windowHeight*0.87,

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change styles to a function that accepts the parameter:

```
function Feed({isProfile}){
    return(
      <View style={createStyles(isProfile).container}>
      </View>

)

}


const createStyles = (profile) => StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
       backgroundColor:colors.primary,                     
       width:windowWidth,
       justifyContent:"center",
       height: profile ? windowHeight : windowHeight*0.87,

    },
```

The `isProfile` variable (prop) is local to the component and invisible outside, so it must be passed as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can store mutiple styles by using an array of objects for style `style={[{},{}]}` etc.. This allows you to add the second part I added

```
function Feed({isProfile}){
    return(
      <View style={[style.container,{height: isProfile ? windowHeight : windowHeight*0.87,}]}>
      </View>

)

}

    
const styles =  StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
       backgroundColor:colors.primary,                     
       width:windowWidth,
       justifyContent:"center",

    },
```